# How to set the customer key of a content block as a var in email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

So I have numerous emails in each journey that when updating it takes way too long to edit and update at the moment.

Right now I've got it down to using shells and then dynamically dumping the body within it.... So I have 2 pieces only in each 'email'..the first being setting the unique name for the rest of the body to be pulled and the following being a call to the block that contains the shell.

How it is now:

```
> %%[VAR @bodytopull
SET @bodytopull = '3MoOv45_HR'
]%%
%%=ContentBlockbyKey("JourneyEmailShell")=%%
<custom name="opencounter" type="tracking"/>
```

I'm hoping to reduce error and future work by having the `@bodytopull` set to the customer key of the email block itself....how would I set that?

basically this would just check what the customer key of the same html email block it is and set it as the `@bodytopull` var.......this would be insanely helpful if possible but I just don't know how to call the value :(

Comment: Maybe it is just me but i dont understand the question. Maybe rephrasing could help. Maybe you look for `%%=ContentBlockbyKey(@bodytopull)=%%`

Comment: well that's the thing. I don't want to pull a block in.... I want the value of bodytopull to use the value of the external key/customer key of the email that it is within......(I know im still not explaining it properly...sorry)

Comment: Do you mean you want the var `@bodytopull` to be inside the sendable data and be able to be referenced inside the content you are pulling in via your `ContentBlockbyKey()` function?

Comment: I would like to have the value of the customer key of the email that it's in to be the value for 'bodytopull' sort of like this: 
SET @bodytopull = Customer Key

I know customer Key used to be External Key before. This value is either automatically generated or you can customize it your email properties.